# Installing SSRS add-in for MOSS 2007 keeps failing

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs, sharepoint-2007

I have a brand new MOSS install (MOSS 2007, Windows Server 2008 x64, SQL 2005 on separate server) and trying to install the add-in for SSRS but it keeps failing. During the install, I keep seeing application events such as these:

> Insufficient SQL database permissions
>   for user 'SYSTEM' in database
>   'SharePoint_AdminContent_d11ed279-c5da-42a0-82e0-b546abf5afdd' on SQL Server instance 'MOSSDB'.
>   Additional error information from SQL
>   Server is included below.
>
> The EXECUTE permission was denied on
>   the object 'proc_EnumLists', database
>   'SharePoint_AdminContent_d11ed279-c5da-42a0-82e0-b546abf5afdd',
>   schema 'dbo'.
>
> Insufficient SQL database permissions
>   for user 'SYSTEM' in database
>   'SharePoint_AdminContent_d11ed279-c5da-42a0-82e0-b546abf5afdd' on SQL Server instance 'MOSSDB'.
>   Additional error information from SQL
>   Server is included below.
>
> The EXECUTE permission was denied on
>   the object 'proc_EnumLists', database
>   'SharePoint_AdminContent_d11ed279-c5da-42a0-82e0-b546abf5afdd',
>   schema 'dbo'.
>
> Insufficient SQL database permissions
>   for user 'SYSTEM' in database
>   'SharePoint_AdminContent_d11ed279-c5da-42a0-82e0-b546abf5afdd' on SQL Server instance 'MOSSDB'.
>   Additional error information from SQL
>   Server is included below.

I have configured all app pool identities to use a domain account as well as giving them permissions to the SP DBs on the SQL server. THe install goes fine until it hangs at "Removing backup files" for a minute or two, then it starts rolling back actions. It ends with a message of "Setup was interrupted before SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Add-In for Sharepoint could be completely installed."

It seems from the documentation that all I do not need any other SQL components on the same box as long as there is a connection to a SQL DB on the back end. Is there anything I'm missing?

EDIT: Couple of things...I keep changing the OfficeServerApplicationPool to use a domain account with DB permissions but it keeps reverting to NetworkService. I'm running the IIS7 console with elevated privileges but can't tell why it keeps going back to it.

Also, I'm using a SQL server alias for back end SQL connections. MOSSDB is setup in cliconfg to send conns to the actual SQL server using TCP/IP 1433.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue after reading an MSDN post here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/880b77ac-3228-40ce-99dc-12b0ff0eb46a

The steps outlined below allowed me to run the msi successfully and then deploy the feature to the farm:

1. Open the commad window (Start>Run type cmd and press enter)
2. Navigate to the path where the installer (SharePointRS.msi) is stored
3. Execute SharePointRS.msi SKIPCA=1  This will do a files only installation of Reporting Services Plug-In
4. CD to %temp%
5. Execute rsCustomAction.exe /i  to auto-configure the installed files.